# Radiation hardened cyclic quine polyglot

Tags: code-challenge, quine, radiation-hardening

### Challenge

Write two programs that:

- run in two different programming languages.

  - These may not be two versions of one language.
- when one program is run, it outputs the second program, and vice versa.
- The two programs must be different (no polyglots).

Here's the catch though:

- The programs must be radiation hardened.

  - This means that when any set of \$n\$ (defined below) characters is removed from either of the two programs, their functionality is unaffected.
  - \$n\$ is defined as the number of characters that may be omitted with your program's functionality unaffected.
  - \$n\$ must be at least \$1\$.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- Your programs must be proper cyclic quines. They may not read their own source code.
- Scoring is performed as follows:

  - Your score is \$\frac{S_1+S_2}n\$…
  - where \$S_1\$ and \$S_2\$ are the size of your first and second programs respectively…
  - and \$n\$ is as defined above.
- This is a [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), lowest score wins.

### Reward

As this challenge is difficult to answer, I will be giving a bounty to the first person to answer.

Comment: Must the programs be proper quines?

Comment: @Mego Whoops - forgot to mention that. Yes.

Comment: Well, "proper quine" isn't the right term since they're not quines, but it seems you understood what I meant.

Comment: @Mego Yeah. I'll fix that now

Comment: Does "Two different programming languages" allow for the use of e.g. Python 2 and Python 3? What about Python 2.5 and Python 2.7?

Comment: @Phoenix Two different versions of a programming language are still one programming language. I should edit that in.

Comment: To confirm: after I remove `n` chars from program 1, should it output the second program, or the second program minus `n` chars?

Comment: @StephenS Second program.

Comment: Personally, I don't think this really adds much to the semiquine and radiation-hardening quine challenges we've already had; both categories have already been thrown together in so many combinations that it's extremely hard to come up with a truly original combination.

Comment: You should probably add some kind of reward for answering this. I feel like it's too extremely difficult for many people to want to try. I saw this had no answers and I was thinking "ooh a quine challenge, I love those!" but then I read **ALL THE RULES** and it completely deterred me.

Comment: @MDXF The description of the challenge is "radiation hardened multi-language cyclic quine". The list of rules is there to establish scoring and stop rule breaking, and to prevent the question from being closed as unclear.

Answer (score 5):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish) and [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), (117 bytes + 117 bytes)/1 = 234

#### Gol><>

```
\\<<'3d*}}}}~}:r0<}!o::! ?>~~a<o>Hr~Kl a}}:?%2l}}}ss2"<<\\
\\<<'3d*}}}}~}:r0<}!o::! ?>~~a<o>Hr~Kl a}}:?%2l}}}ss2"<<\\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/PybGxkbdOEWrFgjqaq2KDGxqFfOtrBQV7O3q6hJt8u08iuq8cxQSa2ut7FWNcoCqiouNlGxsYmK4yNf6/z8A)

#### ><>

```
\\<<"2ss}}}l2%?:}}a lK~rH>o<a~~>? !::o!}<0r:}~}}}}*d3'<<\\
\\<<"2ss}}}l2%?:}}a lK~rH>o<a~~>? !::o!}<0r:}~}}}}*d3'<<\\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PybGxkbJqLi4trY2x0jV3qq2NlEhx7uuyMMu3yaxrs7OXkHRyipfsdbGoMiqtg6oqlYrxVjdxiYmhot8rf//AwA)

[Verification!](https://tio.run/##nVNNb5swGD7jX/GGaTIsHVnam0dTaZO2STvssGOIKgtMsEptyzaNoon89fR1IDTSlss4ILCfr/cBm71vtLo7ymejrQftiLF6a/kz3IOllB6LIs/pXfWhx@vQM/sp72easRk8rA4HnuvVD3v42QLve/bw/rZFlHO3cZ4XBfl/6hGd10v2cbnBOFL5hH7ZewGl7pRn9AZaoZIxZyZUqSuRUO5KKWmapoSQStRQNqJ8erS8ktxLPeFvAPWENVbgPWWERAFsO/U4As5A3IuinfQNaIN2NLigNd3RFLiDOmxHdbaz0ouJg2so3FmFTWbmRKxjM3QMfy6cewh6cZpZwasEeSTSnTedD73/IwzmROLL14ZbRFD6GRdqbUHiOGC52orkopT0FF7WML6v5QZm93BWYADv4PeTNCArobwseYtxlBNl5@UL9owYXmJKF2bU10KtGcrO3zzmS7YJDQTjQELHYSYGYynfeOtEQFzM8haRTN2dWIRMjVz9lvFCG7/Y6raWrlk4W56fM7OP0/Hnib/rdpWv4NcQplDxfFBOrzsMG2eDk/pfslc0uXMiHKVReprw@Ao)

These two programs are the same, just reversed. They both follow the same general code structure.

#### Explanation (Gol><> on top, ><> on the bottom)

```
\\<<                           <<\\  Transition to the copy of the code that is not radiated
\\<<                           <<\\

                              "    Wrapping string literal over the rest of the code
                              '

                           ss2     Push the string character
                           *3d

                        }}}        Rotate the "<<\" to the correct end of the stack
                        }}}

                 }}:?%2l           Use the extra \ to replace a possible irradiated copy
                    }~}:

       ~     lK                    Duplicate the code
        ~~>? !::o!}<0r             Print a copy of the code in reverse

                a                  Push a newline
       a
    Hr                             Reverse, print the rest of stack and terminate
    >o<                            Print the rest of the stack and terminate
```